# Efficient way to select records missing in another table

Tags: sql, database, join

I have 3 tables. Below is the structure:

- `student` (`id int, name varchar(20)`)
- `course` (`course_id int, subject varchar(10)`)
- `student_course` (`st_id int, course_id int`) -> contains name of students who enrolled for a course

Now, I want to write a query to find out students who did not enroll for any course. As I could figure out there are multiple ways to fetching this information. Could you please let me know which one of these is the most efficient and also, why. Also, if there could be any other better way of executing same, please let me know.

```
db2 => select distinct name from student inner join student_course on id not in (select st_id from student_course)

db2 => select name from student minus (select name from student inner join student_course on id=st_id)

db2 => select name from student where id not in (select st_id from student_course)
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I don't know why you'd phrase it as "join vs normal" - in my experience, *most* queries contain at least one join. That being said, I wouldn't use your first example since it's not really using a join in any sane fashion (A `left join`, on the other hand, would be a worthwhile inclusion in the list). But most questions about efficiency in SQL tend to more come down to the available indexes and not doing anything too odd (such as your first query)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Damien!! I agree the first query actually is too odd and practically doesn't make any sense...I was just trying to explore the options.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The subqueries you use, whether it is `not in`, `minus` or whatever, are generally inefficient. Common way to do this is `left join`:

```
select name 
from student 
left join student_course on id = st_id
where st_id is NULL
```

Using `join` is "normal" and preffered solution.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical (maybe even *synoptic*) idiom is (IMHO) to use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT *
FROM student st
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM student_course
  WHERE st.id = nx.st_id
  );
```

Advantages:

- `NOT EXISTS(...)` is very old, and most optimisers will know how to handle it
- , thus it will probably be present on all platforms
- the `nx.` correlation name is not *leaked* into the outer query: the `select *` in the outer query will only yield fields from the `student` table, and not the (null) rows from the `student_course` table, like in the `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE ... IS NULL` case. This is especially useful in queries with a large number of range table entries.
- `(NOT) IN` is error prone (NULLs), and it might perform bad on some implementations (duplicates and NULLs have to be removed from the result of the uncorrelated subquery)

Answer (score 0):

Using "not in" is generally slow.  That makes your second query the most efficient.  You probably don't need the brackets though.

Comment: What makes you think that `not in` is slow and `minus` is not? I'd say both are slow

Comment: @Tomas Could you please explain how join is better than 'not in' and 'minus' in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Just as a comment: I would suggest to select student Id (which are unique) and not names.

As another query option you might want to join the two tables, group by student_id, count(course_id) having count(course_id) = 0.

Also, I agree that indexes will be more important.