# How to filter results of left join based on third table

Tags: sql, database, join

Expanding on this question here: [Efficient way to select records missing in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17380164/1689220), say I have the following 3 tables (original example, see better example below):

```
request: (id, name)
response: (id, request_id, provider_id, resource)
provider: (id, name)
```

First, I want to retrieve all requests for which there does NOT exist a result. This is easy, using a `LEFT JOIN`. I **also** want any `requests` that have not been performed for a given `provider`. **In plain English**: I want all requests for which there are no results OR only results for OTHER providers.

Here is a better example:

```
customer: (id, email)
vehicle: (id, modelname)
testdrive: (id, vehicle_id REFERENCES vehicle(id), customer_id REFERENCES customer(id)
```

Say Bob, Alice, Mary, Fred and Joe visit a car dealership. Bob and Alice test drive the Camry, Bob and Mary test drive the Accord, and Fred and Joe don't test drive anything. The dealership would like to make two lists:

1. Who did NOT test drive the Camry? Mary, Fred, Joe
2. Who did NOT test drive the Accord? Alice, Fred, Joe

Here is a SQL Fiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/80d6a

The following was suggested, but it's not quite correct (see in SQL Fiddle link above) because it also gives me the people who DID test drive the OTHER vehicle models:

```
SELECT c.email
FROM customer AS c
    LEFT JOIN testdrive AS t ON c.id=t.customer_id
    LEFT JOIN vehicle AS v ON t.vehicle_id=v.id AND v.modelname='Camry'
WHERE v.id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/80d6a/8)

**PostgreSQL 9.3 Schema Setup**:

```
BEGIN;

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customer;
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS vehicle;
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS testdrive;

CREATE TABLE customer (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    email TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE vehicle (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    modelname TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE testdrive (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    vehicle_id INTEGER REFERENCES vehicle(id),
    customer_id INTEGER REFERENCES customer(id)
);

INSERT INTO customer (email) VALUES
    ('Bob@foo.org'), ('Alice@bar.net'), ('Mary@baz.com'),
    ('Fred@int.edu'), ('Joe@mut.var');

INSERT INTO vehicle (modelname) VALUES ('Camry'), ('Accord');

INSERT INTO testdrive (vehicle_id, customer_id)
VALUES
    (1, 1), -- Camry, Bob
    (1, 2), -- Camry, Alice
    (2, 1), -- Accord, Bob
    (2, 3); -- Accord, Mary

-- Fred and Joe never test drove anything.
-- Mary didn't test drive the Camry.
-- Alice didn't test drive the Accord.

-- How do I query to find the list of customers who didn't test
-- drive anything, for each vehicle model?

-- Customers who didn't test drive the Camry:
-- Mary, Fred, Joe
SELECT c.email
FROM customer AS c
    LEFT JOIN testdrive AS t ON c.id=t.customer_id
    LEFT JOIN vehicle AS v ON t.vehicle_id=v.id AND v.modelname='Camry'
WHERE v.id IS NULL;

-- Customers who didn't test drive the Accord:
-- Alice, Fred, Joe

COMMIT;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer c
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
( SELECT * 
  FROM testdrive t 
  INNER JOIN vehicle v 
     on v.id = t.vehicle_id
  WHERE v.modelname = 'Camry' AND t.customer_id = c.id)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/80d6a/8/0)**:

```
| id |        email |
|----|--------------|
|  3 | Mary@baz.com |
|  4 | Fred@int.edu |
|  5 |  Joe@mut.var |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer c
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
( SELECT * 
  FROM testdrive t 
  INNER JOIN vehicle v 
     on v.id = t.vehicle_id
  WHERE v.modelname = 'Accord' AND t.customer_id = c.id)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/80d6a/8/1)**:

```
| id |         email |
|----|---------------|
|  2 | Alice@bar.net |
|  4 |  Fred@int.edu |
|  5 |   Joe@mut.var |
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.email
FROM  customer AS c
WHERE NOT c.customer_ID IN (SELECT customer_id FROM testdrive WHERE vehicle_id=@Camry);
```