# how do I select a record which is not present in other related table using sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables like below

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Languages](
    [Title] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Language] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LocalizationKeys](
    [Key] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_LocalizationKey] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LocalizationValues](
    [Value] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [LanguageId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [LocalizationKeyId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_LocalizationValue] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

with following data

```
Languages
Title   Description Id
en-US   English     C3B95465-0B0B-4B97-8C60-19D611F6A185
fi-FI   Finnish     7EDF3C04-3846-4B01-8045-315E26D05CD1

LocalizationKeys
Key Id
Save    A4B7E6DE-BBCE-40FB-8F0E-FE1034B2CAAF

LocalizationValues
Value   LanguageId                              LocalizationKeyId                       Id
Save    C3B95465-0B0B-4B97-8C60-19D611F6A185    A4B7E6DE-BBCE-40FB-8F0E-FE1034B2CAAF    6EB167F5-550B-435E-B6B3-35A02F21F630
```

Now here in above `LocalizationValues table` value for `language fi-FI` is missing for `LocalizationKeyId='A4B7E6DE-BBCE-40FB-8F0E-FE1034B2CAAF'`

> so I want to find it out by giving LanguageId which LocalizationKeyId
>   is missing for that LanguageId
>   I have tested this query for record - it is not working

```
select  locvalue.LocaliZationKeyId, locvalue.LanguageId 
from languages lang left join localizationvalues locvalue
on lang.Id = locvalue.LanguageId
left join [LocalizationKeys] locKey
on lockey.Id = locvalue.LocalizationKeyId
```

Comment: Simply a `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: nope not working I tried :( its little different as values are not present there is no null check too nor a 2 table join kindly check question

Comment: Why didn't a `left join` work? Could you share that query?

Comment: test this for record not working :(
`select  locvalue.LocaliZationKeyId, locvalue.LanguageId 
from languages lang left join localizationvalues locvalue
on lang.Id = locvalue.LanguageId
left join [LocalizationKeys] locKey
on lockey.Id = locvalue.LocalizationKeyId
`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient way to select records missing in another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380164/efficient-way-to-select-records-missing-in-another-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` for this:

```
SELECT [Key], Id
FROM LocalizationKeys AS lk
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Languages AS l
                  JOIN LocalizationValues AS lv ON l.Id = lv.LanguageId
                  WHERE l.Title = 'fi-FI' AND lv.LocalizationKeyId = lk.Id)
```

The above query returns the `LocalizationKeyId` value that is missing for a specified `LanguageId`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/282a4/2)

Comment: fantastic ! Giorgos :) working like charm, thanks  a ton!

Comment: need a help to convert to linq I tried like this 
`   var result = 
              (from lk in localizationKey    
    where !(from l in lang
   join lv in localizationValue on l.Id equals lv.LanguageId
            where l.Title == "en-US" && lv.LocalizationKeyId == lk.Id select l)    
           
    select lk).ToList();`

Comment: @Neo You can try posting a new question. It is not advisable to answer questions in comments.

Comment: Asked new please chek here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36326800/sql-query-to-linq-syntax-using-not-exist-and-join

Answer (score 1):

try below query...

```
select * from Languages l 
inner join LocalizationKeys lk on 1=1
left join LocalizationValues lv on lv.LanguageId = l.id and lv.LocalizationKeyId =  lk.id
```

if you find LocalizationValues fields values is null then its missing