# SQL Query to LINQ syntax using not exist and join

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

My SQL query is like below working fine in SQL 
I need to convert this to LINQ syntax

SQL-

```
SELECT [Key], Id
FROM LocalizationKeys AS lk
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Languages AS l
                  JOIN LocalizationValues AS lv ON l.Id = lv.LanguageId
                  WHERE l.Title = 'en-US' AND lv.LocalizationKeyId = lk.Id)
```

LINQ syntax I tried

```
var result = 

(from lk in localizationKey    
where !(from l in lang
        join lv in localizationValue on l.Id equals lv.LanguageId
        where l.Title == "en-US" && lv.LocalizationKeyId == lk.Id select 1).FirstOrDefault()   

 select lk).ToList();
```

Getting error:

> Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'int'

Any clue where I made mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
(from lk in localizationKey    
where (from l in lang
        join lv in localizationValue on l.Id equals lv.LanguageId
        where (l.Title == "en-US" && lv.LocalizationKeyId == lk.Id)   
       select l).FirstOrDefault() == null
 select lk).ToList();
```

or

```
(from lk in localizationKey    
where !(from l in lang
        join lv in localizationValue on l.Id equals lv.LanguageId
        where !(l.Title == "en-US" && lv.LocalizationKeyId == lk.Id) 
        select l).FirstOrDefault().Any()
 select lk).ToList();
```

Comment: it should be the opposite logic in the first example `FirstOrDefault() == null` and

Comment: getting - A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause

Comment: yeah my fault i fixed it ty @AlexArt.

Comment: thanks working fine on linqPAD but inside my c# app it is fetching all records :( why ?

Comment: `.FirstOrDefault().Any()` - You don't need to do `.FirstOrDefault()` before `Any()`  it needs to be just `.Any()`

Comment: I think issue is I'm taking table values inside var variable thats why may be it is wrong? any clue ? I'm getting all localizationKey values as a output

Comment: Do you want just  Id? @Neo

Answer (score 2):

I think your original query is fine you just need to add another pair of brackets in the where clause:

```
(from lk in localizationKey     
  where !((from l in lang
        join lv in localizationValue on l.Id equals lv.LanguageId
        where l.Title == "en-US" && lv.LocalizationKeyId == lk.Id select 1).Any())
 select lk).ToList();
```

Comment: I think issue is I'm taking table values inside var variable thats why may be it is wrong? any clue ? I'm getting all localizationKey values as a output

Comment: Then most probably the issue is with your sql query. I assume that it returns the same result

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(from lk in localizationKey    
where (from l in lang
        join lv in localizationValue on l.Id equals lv.LanguageId
        where !(l.Title == "en-US" && lv.LocalizationKeyId == lk.Id) select 1).FirstOrDefault()   

 select lk).ToList();
```

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'

Comment: I think issue is I'm taking table values inside var variable thats why may be it is wrong? any clue ? I'm getting all localizationKey values as a output